# Groovy Can't Exec wmic on winserver 2003

Tags: groovy, wmic

Any clue as to what's my blocker in an attempt to run an external process via groovy on windows 2003?

When I execute "wmic process get processid" on commandline with same path as groovy exec this works producing output.  On winserver 2008, this works.  On 2003 it doesn't even if I add "cmd /c ..."   I also tried using "wmic quit" and I continue to get a non zero result code.  So, I don't think groovy can exec wmic on this version of windows.

I'm baffled as to what is different between the two environments.

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer()
StringBuffer err = new StringBuffer()

def process = "wmic process get processid".execute()
process.consumeProcessOutput(output,err)
process.waitForOrKill(7000)

println "Output:\n${output.size()}\nErr:\n${err.size()}\n${output}\n${err}"
```

Comment: have you tried `['wmic', '...'].execute()`?

Comment: I didn't but "wmic ...."  works on 2008 so I'm not sure why I'd need a different approach in 2003

Comment: ah i did not notice, that the difference is within the OS.  does the error code hold any clue for this particular application?  `err` is empty?  could it be a simple problem with the environment/path setup?

Comment: Alas not.  It is 1 on fail and 0 on success.  No error stream output.  I have a few 2003 system of which I plan to replace but I'm concerned I'll hit this later on on 2008 as I don't understand the driver.